# Simulator iOS 4.2

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Is it possible to test an app using the old simulator 4.2 or 4.0?

I downloaded the simulator 4.3 and the "device debugging support iOS 4.9-4.1" from Xcode, clicking on "more simulators", but this only allows me to test on a real device mounting 4.0 or 4.1 that I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of the simulator are no longer supported. The Apple stance seems to be if you want to support iOS <4.3 then you need to test on a device, or run an older version of XCode on an older version of OS X.